# Compile, bundle and minify typescript into JavaScript using VS2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, bundling-and-minification, source-maps, web-essentials

I have a group of typescript files in my solution and I am compiling these to JS using typescript features directly within Visual Studio 2017. I am using tsconfig.json file.

I am able to bundle the output JS files in either VS or tsconfig.

I am able to use WebEssentials to minify and map `*bundle.js.min` back to `*.bundle.js`

What is the correct sequence for compiling, bundling, minifying and mapping within VS2017?

```
- project.csproj
  - scripts //output files
    - my.bundle.js
    - my.bundle.min.js
    - my.bundle.min.js.map
  - src //input files
    - mytypes.ts
    - mylogic.ts
    - mybaselogic.ts
```

(NOTE: I don't want to add the burden of WebPack, Babel or Grunt to my solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is you can get very far with the limited toolset of Typescript and Web Essentials.

The key step is to create a `tsconfig.json` in your `src` directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "amd",                          /* Specify module code generation: */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outFile": "../scripts/bundle.js",   
  }
}
```

and add a NuGet package to `Typescript`. This will alter your project automatically to automatically recreate `bundle.js` on each build.

You are now able to import the bundled javascript files using an AMD loader like `almond.js`:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/almond@0.3.3/almond.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // assuming your program logic is here
    require('mylogic');
</script>
```

Comment: This does not minify as far as I know, it only bundles into a single file